# Why I have to refresh my app to show the right screen to the logged in user?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I have multiple users in my app, and I can login smoothly but when I logout and I login as second user I still can see the first user screens until I refresh my app then I can see the second user screen?

Here is my code:

```
const UserInbox = () => {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    const message = db.collection('feedback').where('recipient','==',userData ? 
    auth.currentUser.email:'unknown')
  


 

    {/*fetch only logged in user messages from database*/}
    const fetchData = async()=>{
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
           
                const list = [];
                if(user){
                await message
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot) => {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const {userId,recipient,messageText} = doc.data()
                         list.push({
                            id:doc.id,
                            userId,
                            recipient,
                            messageText
                         })
                        
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        console.log(doc.data().messageText);
                      
                    });
                    setUserData(list)
                })
                 } else{
                   setUserData(null)
               }  
        })
        return () => unsubscribe(); 
    }
```

I was trying to fix it but I couldn't figure it out because when I look at my code I don't see any errors but I feel I'm missing something? so please do anyone can help me out to display the right screen for the right logged in without refreshing the app with every single login.

Comment: Can you elaborate how are you handling screen like via react navigation?

Comment: Yes, using the react navigation